# Dragging a movieclip as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, drag

I have a Movieclip which is a child of another movieclip. I use startDrag() and stopDrag() with first (parent) Movieclip but the nested one doesnt move.  Why?

### relevant code on stage:

```
var main:rt = new rt(); // rt being a class in my library, which extends MovieClip object.
addChild(main);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stage_mousedownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_mouseupHandler);


function stage_mousedownHandler(event_object:Event) {
    main.startDrag();       
}

function stage_mouseupHandler(event_object:Event) {
    main.stopDrag();
}
```

rt's constructor code:

```
public function rt() {

   var bmp_bar:Bitmap;
   var br_male:Bar_male; // Bar_male is a Bitmap in my library. (AS Linkage)

   bmp_bar = new Bitmap(br_male);
   this.addChild(bmp_bar);
}
```

Comment: @Baris Usakli Sorry, should've been more clear. edited my first post.

Comment: Are you sure there is a child under rt? When you create a child in as3 and add it to main does it move with it?

Comment: @Baris Usakli  In 'rt' class's constructor I add a Bitmap from the library as a child of rt. and as you see, then rt is added to the main stage. I can see the bitmap appearing, so I'm sure there is a child under rt. But I'm still unable to drag it.

Comment: Since you are calling startDrag on the main object it will only drag main but it's children should move with it AFAIK, add the constructor code of rt too.

Comment: are you sure you put rt() in it's own file?  Only thing I can think of is (this.addChild) is scoping your document class.

Comment: You need to make a new instance of Bar_male: var br_male:Bar_male = new Bar_male()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made this simple program to test and it works as expected in Flash Develop, there is a main sprite and a child bitmap when I mouse down any where on stage the main sprite is dragged and the child bitmap is moved.

So I am guessing there is something going on in your workflow in flash professional and linkage. Make sure the mouse event handlers are triggered put some breakpoints and debug.

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        private var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public function Test() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100,false,0x000000);
            bmpData.fillRect(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), 0xff0000);

            var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpData);

            sp.addChild(bmp);

            addChild(sp);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
        }

        private function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            sp.stopDrag();
        }

        private function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            sp.startDrag();
        }

    }

}
```